# Where is TFS work item help text displayed?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm creating some custom work items in TFS and the helptext field seems handy but I don't see where it is being displayed in Team Explorer or Team System Web Access.

**Where is this information displayed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover over the type of the field.  For instance create a new bug and hover over the "rank" and you should see "Stack rank used to prioritize work"